# Neo4j - transactions rolled back

Tags: neo4j

```
$ match (d:Description) with d limit 30000 delete d;                   
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 30000
811 ms

TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
```

Don't know how to fix it? Cannot add cannot delete.
It is failing even for a smaller number of records.

I also reboot the server several times. No improvement.
FinalLy I got this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Description) DELETE n;               
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 2150218
16939 ms
Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Not sure how this can be fixed.

Comment: Not sure about the first one.  On the second one, you  need more java heap memory; it would appear your transaction is being done in memory and you don't have enough to keep that big of a transaction in memory.  Try deleting smaller batches or increase memory

Comment: I reboot the server and I attempted to delete 1 (ONE) node. Got the same error.

Comment: match (n:Description) with n limit 1 DELETE n;                       
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 1
61 ms
TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.

Comment: What do your logs say for the first one? Look in `data/graph.db/messages.log` and in `data/log/*.log`.

Comment: data/log/*.log does not exists. The last entry in the data/graph.db/messages.log is about --- SERVER STARTED END --- If another folder "log" exists somewhere I don't know where it is.

Comment: All my files about the database are in this folder /home/ubuntu/data/neo4j-data/graph2.db

Comment: Found 2 more log files in the folder /var/log/neo4j. The file names are: neo4j.0.0.log and console.log. No information there than server restart related. Transactions are not logged here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am suspecting that under some circumstances the data files are corrupted (see the case deletions are still not committed and rolled back after server reboot) I created a new issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5034
In my case in order to move forward I dropped the database and reloaded from scratch. These was a three hours effort and works only in case of development. Definitively not a solution for production environments.